# Certain UWP Apps Won't Install From the Microsoft Store

Tags: windows-10, uwp, microsoft-store

As it currently stands there are five UWP apps that won't install for me.

- Windows Terminal Preview
- Slack
- Xbox
- Xbox Game Bar
- Skype

I've used WSReset.exe and that didn't help, I tried to install Windows Terminal using the .msixbundle file that Microsoft provides on Github, and I've tried to install the apps directly (the direct method I used is this command in a folder that contains a UWP app `Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register .\AppxManifest.xml`) which also fails.  Those last two methods both fail with this error:

```
App installation failed with error message: AppxManifest.xml(50,14): error 0x80070005: Cannot register the Microsoft.WindowsTerminalPreview_1.0.1402.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe package because the following error was encountered while registering the windows.appExecutionAlias extension: Access is denied.
Try again and contact the package publisher if the problem persists. (0x80070005)
```

Oddly enough, since the apps do download, I'm able to run Terminal directly from its folder. I have no idea why this is happening and I'd love to get pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried running the `add-appxpackage` command elevated as administrator?